# Customer Query - SQL (Magento 2)

Tags: customer, sql

I want to build a sql query for customer. Information needed:

- customer-email
- customer-type (individual user, company admin,
  company user)

Can you help me to build such a query?

BR

Comment: Which Magento version?

Comment: Take a look at ``customer_entity`` table

Answer (score 0):

SELECT email, customer_type

FROM customer_entity

WHERE email = 'example@example.com'

AND (customer_type = 'individual' OR customer_type = 'company_admin' OR customer_type = 'company_user');